# Index out of range error when creating a random list with no consecutive repetitions

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to generate a list of 100 elements which consist of the numbers 1 to 4 randomly distributed, but without consecutive repetitions. I do not want to determine whether the numbers 1 to 4 occur the same number of times, I want it to be completely random except for having no consecutive repetitions. I wrote some code that seems to be doing that until it stops and says 
`list index out of range`, however I cannot figure out why this error is happening.

```
from random import randint

guesses = []

for x in range (0, 99):

    guess = randint(1,4)
    guesses.append(guess)

    if x> 0 and guesses[x] == guesses[x-1]:
       guesses.remove(guess)

 print(guesses)
```

It should look something like this:

```
123421342312321423124213...23142314213
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the number keeps increasing even when you remove a number instead of decreasing. I would recommend using a while loop instead. Also, you should only add the number to your list if needed instead of adding it then removing it.

```
from random import randint

guesses = [randint(1,4)]
x = 1

while x < 100:

    guess = randint(1,4)

    if guess != guesses[x-1]:
       guesses.append(guess)
       x += 1

print(guesses)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work if instead of removing the element that matches the one before, you replace it until it doesn't:

```
from random import randint

guesses = [randint(1,4)]

for x in range (1, 100):

    guess = randint(1,4)
    guesses.append(guess)

    while guesses[x] == guesses[x-1]:
        guesses[x] = randint(1,4)
```

**Two alternate ideas:**

You could create a set of your choices:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

And then on each iteration ask for a `random.choice` from the set - the last item. `choice` needs something indexible so you need to convert to a list each time, but there might be some ways to make that more efficient if this is a bottleneck:

```
from random import choice

choices = {1, 2, 3, 4}
l = [choice(list(choices))]  # start with one random choice

for i in range(99):
    l.append(choice(list(choices - {l[-1]})))
```

This seems to be pretty uniform:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(l)
counts

Counter({3: 26, 2: 25, 1: 26, 4: 23})
```

**Use Iterators**
You can do this all with iterators that evaluate lazily, then just take an `islice()` of the length you want:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import tee, islice

#generator to makes random ints between start and stop
def randIt(start, stop):
    while True:
        yield randint(1,4)

rands, prevs = tee(randIt(1, 4))
next(prevs)

# non_dupes is a generator that makes non-repeating rands
non_dupes = (r for r, i in zip(rands, prevs) if r!=i)

# use itertools islice or a loop to get the number you want
# or just call `next(non_dupes)` for one:
list(islice(non_dupes, 0, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution using numpy

```
from time import time

import numpy as np



def solve_random_non_consecutive(minValue,maxValue,size):
    # initial guess
    a = np.random.randint(minValue,maxValue,size)
    # indexes where a[i] == a[i-1]
    x = np.where(np.diff(a) == 0)[0]
    # as long as we have consecutive duplicates
    while len(x) > 0:
        # rerandomize all indexes
        a[x] = np.random.randint(minValue,maxValue,len(x))
        # find all duplicates
        x = np.where(np.diff(a) == 0)[0]
    return a

s = time()
print(solve_random_non_consecutive(1,5,1000000))
print("Took %0.2fs to solve"%(time()-s)) # took ~ 0.17 seconds to generate 1MIL 
# any of the solutions using iteration took ~ 10 seconds to generate 1 mil
```

some caveats are that since its repopulating the data randomly the amount of time may vary from run to run

Answer (score 0):

You're only generating 99 elements. Range(0,99) goes from 0 to 98 including 0 to total 99 elements.

Also, the part of your code which removes duplicate guesses needs to set x back to x - 1. This way the "counter" for each element you want to create is not 1 ahead of how many elements you actually have.

Additionally, when you remove this element, that method will remove the first instance of a object equal to the variable guess, not necessarily the one you just added. You should use .pop() View the example in python I screenshotted.

```
for x in range (0, 100):

    guess = randint(1,4)
    guesses.append(guess)

    if x> 0 and guesses[x] == guesses[x-1]:
       guesses.pop()
       x = x - 1
```

[image]

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem this week, my solution was that I had to adjust my counter(x it looks like for you) every time I removed an index because the array gets shorter so things start to shift around.

Comment: You should add code showing the change as well as describing it.

Comment: I can only write JS so far as I'm still pretty new to programming and I didn't want seem too dumb :) Just started learning Python this week though.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element from the guesses array, its length will decrement

use this code

```
from random import randint

guesses = []
x = 0
while x < 100:

    guess = randint(1,4)
    guesses.append(guess)

    if x > 0 and guesses[x] == guesses[x-1]:
        guesses.pop()
    else:
        x += 1

print(guesses)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is once you remove an element, x becomes larger than the size of your array

so guesses[x] is out of bounds because  x >= guesses.size()